# Spring Security and() method

Tags: spring-security

In spring framework security, there is an example:

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login") 1
        .permitAll();
```

Anyone who knows when is and() be used?  It is defined at ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry, not easy to read springs documentation, seems designed to confuse.

Answer (score 11):

Think of `and()` as a way to chain methods together. You typically use an `and()` method after you're done configuring options on that particular *Configurer*. So for example,

```
http
    .someConfigurer
        .<some feature of configurer>()
        .<some feature of configurer>()
        .and()
    .someOtherConfigurer
        .<some feature of someOtherConfigurer>()
        ...
        .and()
     ...
```

You'll notice that the first level of calls on the `http` object are 
Configurers

```
.formLogin() --> FormLoginConfigurer
.httpBasic() --> HttpBasicConfigurer()
.sessionManagement() --> SessionManagementConfigurer
```

The next level after the Configurer are properties of that particular configurer that you want to tweak. For e.g.

```
formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login")
    .permitAll()
    .and()
```

The `and()` at the end of this returns a *builder* (`HttpSecurity` in our case). And hence we can chain other configurers using the `and()` method.

The method itself comes from [`SecurityConfigurerAdapter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/SecurityConfigurerAdapter.java) class. The `and()` method in `ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry` in turn calls the above method.

Answer (score 1):

I interpret the question as why there is a need to add "and()" for some methods and not for others.

For this, my answer is it depends on the return type of the previous method.

**No need to** add "and()" when return type is HttpSecurity

E.g
crsf().disable(): return type HttpSecurity

(I don’t understand why the return type is HttpSecurity, maybe it call the disable function and hence nothing returned?)

**Add** "and()" for other return types

E.g
cors(): return type CorsConfigurer
formLogin(): return type FormLoginConfigurer

Comment: Can you post a few _minimum viable code samples_ that demonstrate this?

Answer (score 0):

Basically and() method is used to concatenate multiple configurer of Spring Security
You can refer attached image to understand more clearly[image: usage of and() method]